# How to call the value of a key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am learning Django. I have an app name **quizes**
In the `models.py` section I have this:

```
from django.db import models


DIFFICULTY_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'easy'), (2, 'intermediate'), (3, 'difficult')
)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    difficulty = models.IntegerField(choices=DIFFICULTY_CHOICES)
```

This is how `views.py` looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Quiz
from django.views.generic import ListView



class QuizListView(ListView):
    model = Quiz
    template_name = 'quizes/main.html'


def quiz_view(request, pk):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'quizes/quiz.html', {'obj': quiz})
```

Now in the `main.html` I have a button that calls these values and it looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal-button" data-difficulty="{{obj.difficulty}}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#quizStartModal">
    Button Name
</button>
```

When the user clicks on the button, I would like to display the value of the key in difficulty. the key is fetched by the button using the `data-difficulty` method.
In the JavaScript part, this is what I am doing:

```
const modalBtns = [...document.getElementsByClassName("modal-button")]
const modalBody = document.getElementById("modal-body-confirm")

modalBtns.forEach(modalBtn=> modalBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    const difficulty = modalBtn.getAttribute('data-difficulty')
    modalBody.innerHTML = `
    <div>
        difficulty: <b>${difficulty}
    </div>
`
```

So I am getting the output as 1 for easy, 2 for intermediate and so on.
**But I want to output the value of those keys instead of those keys themselves. How do I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the choice field value, use the following format in your template.

```
{{ obj.get_fieldname_display }}
```

So change `{{ obj.difficulty }}` to `{{ obj.get_difficulty_display }}`.

Full context.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal-button" data-difficulty="{{ obj.get_difficulty_display }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#quizStartModal">
    Button Name
</button>
```

Comment: That's great, you can mark the answer as accepted.